# Wheren does the task vector resides in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

Processes' task_struct are stored in task_vector in Linux OS. Is there any way to view this task vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information using the pstree command.

Comment: Could you please give format of the command? I'm not being lazy but just want the best format to view.

Comment: you probably want pstree pid  or pstree user.